# Deployment strategy in Production

Tags: deployment, production

Hi I need any advice on how to manage production deployment in SharePoint with regards on Intranet Portal changes.

Right now we have group of developers updating the production site and anyone can change the site and we don't know who fixed or did some changes.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

This is not related to SharePoint but to your management and company. There is always a Change control method that you can implement, you do not need some fancy software just the willingness of the people to participate. If you are the manager of the developers it should be easy to impose, if you are not their manager then it's about internal politics.